# Rails 3 , help with setting up a config for a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the resource photos

Currently I have this working: /photos

which shows the photos#index controller which is what I want...

But now I want to also have /projects/2/photos

Which should show photos for that project. Problem is that is pointing to the def index, and somehow I need a separate view for this path.

Thoughts? Thanks

routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :photos,do
  collection do
    get 'newjs'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `PhotosController#index` action you can check to see if `params[:project_id]` is defined -- if it is then you are using the sub-resource. If it is not, you are using the top-level resource.

Comment: Thanks ben but - That's seems really messy, no? to have a big if statement for totally different views in the def#index?

Comment: Two different views? Or two different sets of controller logic? If the controller logic is really that different, then there is likely something amiss with the structure of your code -- either you should be refactoring some of that code into models, or you shouldn't be trying to let one resource act as both a top-level resource and a sub-resource. If you do want to treat one resource this way, I believe that checking for params[:project_id] is that idiomatic and correct way of doing it. Maybe if you elaborate a little more on the details I can give a better answer.

Comment: oh, also, I need different view pages, something like project_photos_index, since the layouts are very different. Thoughts?

Comment: @ Ben, good point the controller logic is super thing. But the two have totally different views.

Comment: to render a different view is easy, just use `render :template => "template/path"` (not the full path with file ending, but path from rails views dir, with no file extension). Alternatively, you can try to use the same template for both indexes, and separate out the parts where they differ by using partials.